# Can I use System.Configuration for working with particular config file?

Tags: .net

If title is not clear: I want to read to and to write from some specific `.xml` configuration file. Is it possible with `System.Configuration`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, and very easily:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets any configuration file configuration file object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">Path to configuration file.</param>
/// <param name="createIfNotExist">If true will create new configuration file if is doesn't exist.</param>
/// <returns>Configuration file object.</returns>
public static Configuration GetFileConfig(string path, bool createIfNotExist)
{
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
                if (createIfNotExist)
                {
                        using (XmlTextWriter xml = new XmlTextWriter(path, null))
                        {
                                xml.WriteStartDocument();
                                xml.WriteStartElement("configuration");
                                xml.WriteStartElement("appSettings");
                                xml.WriteEndElement();
                                xml.WriteStartElement("connectionStrings");
                                xml.WriteEndElement();
                                xml.WriteEndElement();
                                xml.WriteEndDocument();
                        }
                }
                else
                {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Path doesn't exist", "path");
                }
        }

        ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = path };

        return ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
}
```

Comment: I don't see where I specify any **concrete** path in your sample.

Comment: Seу update, path is in object initializer of ExeConfigurationFileMap.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

The classes in the namespace only recognize `.config` files in the expected locations (app folder, web.config files and linked config files from those).

It is such trouble to rename a file to `.config` from `.xml`?

Update (following comment):

You can use [`ConfigSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) in a configuration section to point to a separate file:

```
<connectionStrings configSourc="myConnectionStrings.config" />
```

Comment: Of course it is not. I just want to store application settings in some specific predefined directory (let they be `.config` files) and I cannot find the way to specify full path to that files.

Comment: @zerkms - look at [`ConfigSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) - this should do what you want.

Comment: @Oded: what if I have no `app.config` file now (it is WPF application though) and path to that file is "current user's AppData directory-based path"?

Comment: @zerkms - Not sure what that is supposed to mean. Config files are loaded once on startup of the app.

Comment: @Oded: I want several config files to be stored in the current user's `AppData` directory. Is it possible to do with `configSource`?

Comment: @zerkms - The path is hard coded, so I don't believe you can. You can experiment with environment variables, however (`%APPDATA%` for instance) as part of the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think u better to have a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configxmldocument.aspx) page

Comment: From the link: `This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.` The class is also marked `sealed` so can't be inherited...